# maven h2 lucene classnotfound

Tags: java, maven, lucene, h2

I use in my project h2 and I like to enable the lucene search index. I added the following deps. to the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
  <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
  <version>4.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
    <artifactId>lucene-analyzers-common</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I still get java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.search.Searcher from h2. This problem only occours when I launch the program.

Comment: Can you please post the output of `mvn dependency:resolve`? And I presume you've done a full clean and revuild?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lucene < 4.0.0; the `org.apache.lucene.search.Searcher` abstract class has been deprecated in version 3.6.0, and then included since 4.0.0 as/inside `org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher`.

http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/core/deprecated-list.html